# MySQL concat according to number of results

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, case, concatenation

I have been researching the answer to my question for two days now and I have not had any luck, probably because I don't know exactly how to describe what I am looking for, as far as the methods I need to use.

Basically within my database, I have two tables, one named tblCounties (ID, County_vc), the other tblOrganizations (ID, Organization_vc).  I have a third table which links the two together, called jnCountyOrg (Org_fk_id, County_fk_id).  One organization can belong to a minimum of one county, up to a maximum of three counties.  When I do a while loop through my select query using php, it echo's the results properly like this:

CountyName1CountyName2CountyName3

I have tried using mysql_fetch_array and mysql_fetch_assoc.

I would like the results to be formatted like so.

IF only one county is associated with an organization, echo "xxx County".

IF two counties associated with organization, then echo "xxx and xxx Counties".

Lastly, if three counties (which is the max) are associated with the organization, then "xxx, xxx and xxx Counties".

I am confused as to whether I am to do this in the SQL using CASE statements, or if I should use php to format my results in this fashion after they are queried from the database.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Better to do this in PHP. it's a display thing - sql should generally just be used for the raw data.

Comment: Agreed with @MarcB - this is possible in SQL but a total PITA and probably less efficient than doing it in PHP.

Comment: For kicks, [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bd62c/1) is a demonstration of why you should do this in PHP and not MySQL. And even that ridiculously complex mechanism still assumes that county names cannot contain an `@`. There may be a simpler way but I can't think of one, MySQL's string manipulation functions leave a lot to be desired...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a [SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a9b24/17). It works also for county count > 3:

```
select id,CompanyNAme,countyCount,countyNAmes,
if(countyCount=1,concat(countyNAmes,' County'),
   if(countyCount=2,concat(REPLACE(countyNAmes,', ',' and '),' Counties'),

         CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(countyNAmes,',',countyCount-1)
            ,' and '
            , SUBSTRING_INDEX(countyNAmes,',',-1)
            ,'  Counties'
            )
      )
) RESULT
from
(
select o.id,max(o.Organization_vc) CompanyNAme,
group_concat(c.County_vc separator ', ') CountyNames,count(c.id) CountyCount 

from tblOrganizations o
left join jnCountyOrg co on (o.id=co.Org_fk_id) 
left join tblCounties c on (co.County_fk_id = c.id)
group by o.id
) m
order by m.id
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time to figure this out for me valexhome.  Works perfectly!  Thanks again!